# Get counts of each type in a `type` column and associate that with a name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a basic table

```
id | type  |            date
---------------------------------------
1  | photo | 2015-11-20
2  | video | 2015-02-1
3  | file  | 2016-01-17
4  | photo | 2016-01-23
5  | photo | 2016-01-27
6  | video | 2016-01-27
```

My very basic query is:

```
  SELECT COUNT(type) FROM fields GROUP BY type;
```

which results in:

```
count
-----
  3
  2
  1
```

Which is close, but how would I associate the type with the number? Ideally would like something close to this:

```
count | type
------------
  3   | photo
  2   | video
  1   | file
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(type), type FROM fields GROUP BY type` ?

Comment: Yep, this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change count(type) by count(*)

```
 SELECT COUNT(*), type FROM fields GROUP BY type
```